# Conversion Error in iterator over vector of unordered_map

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, unordered-map

I have a simple program where I want to iterate over a vector of unordered maps. I'm new to STL and don't know why there is a problem in conversion. The code is as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t> umap1{ { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t> umap2{ { 7, 8 }, { 9, 10 }, { 11, 12 } };
std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t> umap3{ { 13, 14 }, { 15, 16 }, { 17, 18 } };

std::vector<std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t>> crd{ umap1, umap2, umap3 };

constexpr uint8_t ZERO = 0;

std::vector<std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t>>::iterator begin()
{
    return crd[ZERO].begin();
}

std::vector<std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t>>::iterator end()
{
    return crd[ZERO].end();
}

int main()
{
    for (auto it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
    {
        for (auto it1 = it->begin(); it1 != it->end(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it1->first << " " << it1->second << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error

```
mytest.cpp(15): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::pair<const uintptr_t,uintptr_t>
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=std::unordered_map<uintptr_t,uintptr_t,std::hash<uintptr_t>,std::equal_to<uintptr_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<const uintptr_t,uintptr_t>>>
        ]
mytest.cpp(15): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
mytest.cpp(20): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::pair<const uintptr_t,uintptr_t>
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=std::unordered_map<uintptr_t,uintptr_t,std::hash<uintptr_t>,std::equal_to<uintptr_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<const uintptr_t,uintptr_t>>>
        ]
mytest.cpp(20): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think `std::map::begin()` would return an `std::vector::iterator`? Do you want to iterate over the maps or iterate over the elements in the first map?

Comment: `crd` is a vector of unordered maps. `crd[ZERO]` is therefore an unordered map. Therefore `crd[ZERO].begin()` is an unordered map iterator, not a vector-of-unordered-map iterator, and therefore does not match the stated return type of the function(s). The error message is *exactly* conveying what you're doing wrong.

Comment: If your compiler support C++14 or later, simply return by `auto`.

Comment: Problem is that you are doing something weird and we do know what it suppose to do. We see that you are trying return an iterator of wrong type, but since we do not understand what is the intent it is impossible to tell how to fix this properly (we can fix compilation error, but most probably it will not do proper thing). IMO this qualifies as [XY probelm](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Isn't this just a silly overthinking what those functions should do? https://godbolt.org/z/ojz88xGbf (note small typo was fixed too). Or simple use of range based loop: https://godbolt.org/z/4shWY5qW6

Comment: Sorry for wasting everybody's time, I messed up the begin and end functions. What I actually wanted is that begin and end return a `std::unordered_map<uintpr_t, uintptr_t>::iterator`. This should not have made it to SO. Apologies.